# ToggleSwitch.On & OffContent Not Updating

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, uwp-xaml, toggleswitch

I'm trying to update three ToggleSwitches' `OnContent` as well as `OffContent` based on values retrieved from the UWP's Local Settings Cache (not the `ToggleSwitch.IsOn` property). Please note that I'm doing this on an external thread.

Here is my current code:

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
public async void updateUI()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        // set Test1 state in UI
        toggleSwitchTest1.OnContent = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test1"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
        toggleSwitchTest1.OffContent = toggleSwitchTest1.OnContent;

        // set Test2 state in UI
        toggleSwitchTest2.OnContent = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test2"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
        toggleSwitchTest2.OffContent = toggleSwitchTest2.OnContent;

        // set Test3 state in UI
        toggleSwitchTest3.OnContent = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test3"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
        toggleSwitchTest3.OffContent = toggleSwitchTest3.OnContent;
     });
}
```

I have also tried doing this with normal `Boolean` values as parameters being passed into the method. Or `Boolean` values just being declared at the beginning of the class before the public constructor and just setting it. This did not work either.

Please let me know if any other code is needed.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I call the `updateUI` method somewhere by simply invoking it like this: `updateUI()`

**Edit 2**

The `ToggleSwitches'` XAML constructor code:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitchTest1" OffContent="It is" OnContent="It is" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOn="False"/>
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitchTest2" OffContent="It is" OnContent="It is" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,116,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOn="False"/>
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitchTest3" OffContent="It is" OnContent="It is" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOn="False"/>
```

Comment: Accessing any UI-based control on different thread than UI thread is not allowed and will cause your app crash. However, in your code itself it seems you are correctly using the `Dispatcher` to let the code run on the UI thread. Please post the code that is calling the `updateUI` method and tell us if you are getting any error or what is the behavior that you want to achieve.

Comment: Also put breakpoints inside the `RunAsync` method to see if the code is actually getting hit.

Comment: @MartinZikmund the `RunAsync` method is indeed getting hit. There are no exceptions or errors getting thrown. I want to change the `OnContent` as well as the `OffContent` based on the UWP App's `LocalSettings`. Please see my edit.

Comment: What does your XAML for these toggles look like?  I wonder if using an intermediary object which has DependencyProperties would help.  Then you could bind your XAML to that object, and then just update its properties in your method.

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT I've added it in my second edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will get `null` value, if you have never apply value to `localSettings.Values["xxx"]`. And if value is null, the [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns false. All the toggleSwitchTest `OnConten` will be set *It is: Off*.

And I found you use `toggleSwitchTest1.OffContent = toggleSwitchTest1.OnContent;` It will cause `OffContent` and `OnConten`to become the same value.

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    var value = localSettings.Values["Test1"];
    // set Test1 state in UI
    toggleSwitchTest1.OnContent = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test1"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
    // toggleSwitchTest1.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test1"]);
    toggleSwitchTest1.OffContent = !(Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test1"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";

    // set Test2 state in UI
    toggleSwitchTest2.OnContent = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test2"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
    //  toggleSwitchTest2.IsOn= Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test2"]);
    toggleSwitchTest2.OffContent = !(Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test2"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";

    // set Test3 state in UI
    toggleSwitchTest3.OnContent = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test3"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
    //   toggleSwitchTest3.IsOn= Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test3"]);
    toggleSwitchTest3.OffContent = !(Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test3"])) ? "It is: On" : "It is: Off";
});
```

Although you could change `off` and `on` content with the above code, it will lead to logic confusion. I suggest you set off and on content in the xaml previous and bind `IsOn` property with localsetting value.

```
toggleSwitchTest1.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["Test1"]);
```

**Edit 1**

As a result of the `AppServiceConnection` methods not having access to the UI, trying to change the UI from a method like this (even when using the `Dispatcher`) would not have an effect.

Rather call it from a method or event like `ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged` which you can invoke through `ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChange()`.

Comment: But the visual aspects still do not change. Only the virtual properties change (according to Visual Studio when debugging). And, yes, I want the `OnContent` and `OffContent` to be the same. The `localSettings` should not change the `IsOn` property, but instead only the `OnContent` and the `OffContent`

Comment: It works in my side, I could not reproduce your issue. Can you share a simple sample?

Comment: Well, the `localSettings.Value` elements are set in a method which is triggered when my WinForm component sends data to my UWP App over the `AppServices` API meaning that I'm going to have to share the whole solution and, no offence, but I don't want source code lying around. Can I send you a similar solution? I'm going to have to make one first, though. Is that okay?

Comment: where should I upload it to?

Comment: You could share  github link.

Comment: Hi, thx for offering, however, I've figured it out. I had to run the code in a loop on a `BackgroundWorker` thread, because the `updateUI()` method was secretly throwing an exception as a result of it being called too quickly before the method could complete. Thanks for offering, though. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Nico, I know it is a month later. I found a problem with my solution which was using the BackgroundWorker. Anyway, if the offer still stands, please view a similar sample here: github.com/dilvermaak/UINotUpdatingFromDispatcher . Thank You

Comment: OK. I will check.

Comment: I have checked your sample, please told me what's the problem in your sample?

Comment: When the `WinForm` sends data to the `UWP` app, the UI doesn't change even though the values change. When you click the Update UI button the UI changes. My question is: how can I get the UI to change (i.e. the images) when the `updateUI()` method gets called from the `Connection_OnRequestReceived` method and not only when I click the Update UI button. Is my question clear or is there still confusion?

Comment: I have tested your sample, but I am strange why `Connection_OnRequestReceived` always invoke ?

Comment: The method always invokes because the WinForm continually sends data to the UWP App on a `Timer`. However, even if it doesn't continually update with a `Timer` it still does the same - as you can see on my latest GitHub Commit (Update).

Comment: Hi Nico, I finally solved the problem by subscribing to the `ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged` event and calling `updateUI()` from there. The `DataChanged` event gets invoked when I call the `ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChange()` method. Should I upload the updated sample? Anyways, thanks for all your help. Much apprieciated.

Comment: Congratulation, you could post your answer here and accept it.

Comment: Or would you like to edit your answer? My way of thanking you.